# Error In PHP5 ..Unable to load dynamic library gd.so

Tags: php

```
litingjun@litingjun-All-Series:/etc/php5/cli/conf.d$ php -a
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/gd.so: undefined symbol: gdImageCreateFromGd2Part in Unknown on line 0

litingjun@litingjun-All-Series:/etc/php5/cli/conf.d$ ls /usr/lib/php5/20121212/gd.so
/usr/lib/php5/20121212/gd.so
```

I've tried reinstalling gd using `sudo apt-get install php5-gd` but still not work.

My PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11

I need gd.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reinstalled my OS and problem's gone.